# True / false written on console , trying to write tests in postman. If false, fail the test

Tags: javascript, postman-testcase

I have contains function that prints in console as true/ false, I need to write a tests in postman so that if found false, fail the tests and can be shown on tests tab. In the below const testfalse= gives the value true or false in console. But if found false, I need to have a tests to fail if fund false. I have tried with if condition, which is not logging anything

```
    // Getting the category name and name key
var categname= pm.environment.get("categoryName");
console.log(categname)
var categnamekey= pm.environment.get("categorynameKey")
console.log(categnamekey)

var arr=JSON.parse(responseBody); 
function contains(arr, key, val) {
    for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
        if(arr[i][key] === val) 
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}

// To verify if value present or not which prints true or false

const testfalse=console.log(contains(arr, "name", categname)); 
console.log(contains(arr,"nameKey",categnamekey));

if(testfalse=='false'){
    tests["fail"]
}else {
    tests["success"]
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `pm.expect(someValue).to.equal(expectedValue)` method to compare if the value is what you expected. If it's not the same, the failed test will show in the result.

Also your `testFalse` should just be the check, you can console.log at any time, it won't affect the test... it will just give you a log to review when the test runs.

```
const testfalse = contains(arr, "name", categname);
console.log('Category found: ' + testfalse); 

 //rest of code here

//Test will either pass or fail after this line and reflect on test tab
pm.expect(testfalse).to.equal(true); //maybe rename testPass
```

https://learning.postman.com/docs/postman/scripts/test-scripts/